# how to schedule a push notification for sometime after entering a region? swift

Tags: swift, push-notification, location, apple-push-notifications

I want to send a schedule a local push notification 20 minutes after entering a region. This is my current code which doesn't work. This is the code in my viewcontroller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NavViewController.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    NavViewController.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        NavViewController.locationManager.delegate = self
        NavViewController.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        NavViewController.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
            notificationSettings.setUpTimeIntervalNotification()
    }
```

and here is the code in my notificationSettings class:

```
class func setUpTimeIntervalNotification(){
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Are you ready to do your exercises?"
    content.body = "Tap to start now."
    content.sound = .default

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (20*60), repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: Notification.Location.rawValue, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

just add this code in appdelegate and it will work fine

```
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Set UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        return true
    }

}
```

// Conform to UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
           willPresent notification: UNNotification,
           withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        completionHandler(.alert)
    }

}
```

Comment: I do have the second part in my view controller. do I ned to add it to appDelegate?

Comment: yes in didFinishlaunching add UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self then add that method